# Haskell way to go about enums

Tags: haskell, types, enumeration

I want to represent a type of the following form :

```
(Card, Suit)
```

to represent cards in a card game where `Card` instances would be in the set:

```
{2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, J, Q, K, 1}
```

and `Suit` would have instances in the set:

```
{S, D, H, C}
```

I'd handle that with two Data declarations if that wasn't for the numbers:

```
data Suit = S | D | H | C deri...
```

but obviously adding numbers to those null arity types will fail.

So my question is, how to simulate the kind of enum you find in C?

I guess I'm misundestanding a basic point of the type system and help will be appreciated!

EDIT: I'll add some context: I want to represent the data contained in [this Euler problem](http://projecteuler.net/problem=54), as you can check, the data is represented in the form of 1S for an ace of spade, 2D for a 2 of diamond, etc...

What I'd really like is to be able to perform a read operation directly on the string to obtain the corresponding object.

Comment: The ability to parse strings like "1S" or "2D" to cards is actually orthogonal to enum representation.

Comment: @MatveyAksenov Well, I do understand that. What I was looking for was the most idiomatic way to do it within the type system. Anyway, I guess I asked the wrong questions.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I actually happen to have an implementation handy from when I was developing a poker bot. It's not particularly sophisticated, but it does work.

First, the relevant types. Ranks and suits are enumerations, while cards are the obvious compound type (with a custom `Show` instance)

```
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec

data Suit = Clubs | Diamonds | Hearts | Spades deriving (Eq,Ord,Enum,Show)

data Rank = Two | Three | Four | Five | Six | Seven | Eight | Nine | Ten
          | Jack | Queen | King | Ace deriving (Eq,Ord,Enum,Show)  

data Card = Card { rank :: Rank
                 , suit :: Suit } deriving (Eq,Ord,Bounded)

instance Show Card where
    show (Card rank suit) = show rank ++ " of " ++ show suit
```

Then we have the parsing code, which uses Parsec. You could develop this to be much more sophisticated, to return better error messages, etc.

Note that, as Matvey said in the comments, the problem of parsing strings into their representations in the program is (or rather *should be*) orthogonal to how the enums are represented. Here I've cheated and broken the orthogonality: if you wanted to re-order the ranks (e.g. to have `Ace` rank below `Two`) then you would break the parsing code, because the parser depends on the internal representation of `Two` being `0`, `Three` being `1` etc..

A better approach would be to spell out all of the ranks in `parseRank` explicitly (which is what I do in the original code). I wrote it like this to (a) save some space, (b) illustrate how it's possible in principle to parse a number into a rank, and (c) give you an example of bad practice explicitly spelled out, so you can avoid it in the future.

```
parseSuit :: Parser Suit
parseSuit = do s <- oneOf "SDCH"
               return $ case s of
                'S' -> Spades
                'D' -> Diamonds
                'H' -> Hearts
                'C' -> Clubs

parseRank :: Parser Rank
parseRank = do r <- oneOf "23456789TJQKA"
               return $ case r of
                'T' -> Ten
                'J' -> Jack
                'Q' -> Queen
                'K' -> King
                'A' -> Ace
                 n  -> toEnum (read [n] - 2)

parseCard :: Parser Card
parseCard = do r <- parseRank
               s <- parseSuit
               return $ Card { rank = r, suit = s }

readCard :: String -> Either ParseError Card
readCard str = parse parseCard "" str
```

And here it is in action:

```
*Cards> readCard "2C"
Right Two of Clubs
*Cards> readCard "JH"
Right Jack of Hearts
*Cards> readCard "AS"
Right Ace of Spades
```

---

**Edit:**

@yatima2975 mentioned in the comments that you might be able to have some fun playing with `OverloadedStrings`. I haven't been able to get it to do much that's useful, but it seems promising. First you need to enable the language option by putting `{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}` at the top of your file, and include the line `import GHC.Exts ( IsString(..) )` to import the relevant typeclass. Then you can make a `Card` into a string literal:

```
instance IsString Card where
    fromString str = case readCard str of Right c -> c
```

This allows you to pattern-match on the string representation of your card, rather than having to write out the types explicitly:

```
isAce :: Card -> Bool
isAce "AH" = True
isAce "AC" = True
isAce "AD" = True
isAce "AS" = True
isAce _    = False
```

You can also use the string literals as input to functions:

```
printAces = do
    let cards = ["2H", "JH", "AH"]
    mapM_ (\x -> putStrLn $ show x ++ ": " ++ show (isAce x)) cards
```

And here it is in action:

```
*Cards> printAces
Two of Hearts: False
Jack of Hearts: False
Ace of Hearts: True
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Quick question: wouldn't it be nicer to make your Card type an instance of Read? I didn't use parsec yet so I do not know if it's common to ignore Read and parse it aside.

Comment: You could add a derived instance of Read, although you'd only gain the ability to parse strings like "Card { rank = Two, suit = Clubs }" which wouldn't be that useful. You could specify a `Read` instance yourself, which essentially comes down to writing a parser for your type. I don't think there's a way to get away with writing any fewer lines than I did here.

Comment: What are the options of now using `OverloadedStringLiterals`? That would get you pretty close to a DSL!

Comment: @yatima2975 I edited to include some information about string literals. Maybe you can flesh it out if you have more experience with that language extension?

Comment: huh, this extension seems to be what I was looking for, in the end. Thanks @yatima2975 for bringing that up :)

Comment: @ChrisTaylor: I think that, by now, you know more about overloaded string literals than I do - good job on the edit!

Answer (score 9):

```
data Card = Two | Three | Four | Five | Six
          | Seven | Eight | Nine | Ten
          | Jack | Queen | King | Ace
    deriving Enum
```

Implementing the `Enum` typeclass means you can use `fromEnum` and `toEnum` to convert between `Card` and `Int`.

However, if it's important to you that `fromEnum Two` is `2`, you will have to implement the `Enum` instance for `Card` by hand. (The autoderived instance starts at `0`, just like C, but there's no way of overriding that without doing it all yourself.)

n.b. You might not need `Enum` --- if all you want is to use operators like `<` and `==` with your `Card`s, then you need to use `deriving Ord`.

---

Edit:

You cannot use `read` to turn a `String` of the form `"2S"` or `"QH"` into a `(Card, Suit)` because `read` will expect the string to look like `"(a,b)"` (e.g. `"(2,S)"` in the form you initially asked for, or `"(Two,S)"` in the form I suggested above).

You will have to write a function to parse the string yourself. You could use a parser (e.g. Parsec or Attoparsec), but in this case it should be simple enough to write by hand.

e.g.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections #-}

parseSuit :: String -> Maybe Suit
parseSuit "S" = Just S
...
parseSuit _   = Nothing

parseCard :: String -> Maybe (Card, Suit)
parseCard ('2' : s) = fmap (Two,) (parseSuit s)
...
parseCard _         = Nothing
```

Answer (score 2):

I’d just prefix the numbers with a letter, or better yet, a word. I’d also not use too many one-letter abbreviations – `H`, `K` etc. are downright unreadable.

```
data Suit = Club | Spade | Heart | Diamond
data Card = Card1 | Card2 | … | Jack | Queen | King | Ace
```

… But I even prefer dave’s suggestion of using the number words (`One`, `Two`) for values instead.